# Error running react-native application with wix@react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I installed `wix/react-native-navigation` and follow all the required configurations to be able to use it in android with react native. But my `npm run android` is not working even though my script is configure in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "android": "cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug"
  },
```

```
npm run android

cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE'''

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! Awesome@0.0.1 android: `cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug 
&& ./gradlew installDebug`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the Awesome@0.0.1 android script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\z0041hhp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-29T09_08_37_797Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you in linux?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with my windows 10, what I did was to remove "./ " I had something like

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "android": "cd android && gradlew app:assembleDebug && gradlew installDebug"
}
```